# Facebook publish to like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Hey is it still possible to post to users who liked a page(Open graph self hosted object)?

This feature was once released and would be so usefull for my project:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/397/

http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/02/23/how-publish-like-button/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're referring to was removed in November 2012 - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any other chance to publish something into the stream to only a selected group of users? creating a facebook page for everything is not possible!

Comment: The use case is a news web portal were users contribute articles and readers can subscribe lists for topics, authors, ... so it would be great to publish news only to a selective group of users. With the old feature this would be easy ...